# Which algorithm can be used to solve this system of equations?

Tags: algorithm, math

`ax + by + cz + dw ≡ 1 (mod p)`

`ex + fy + gz + hw ≡ 1 (mod p)`

(`p` is prime, `0 <= a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h < p`, `0 <= x,y,z,w < p`, all varients are integer)

I only know the values of `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`, and I have to get `x, y, z, w`.

How can I solve this using computer? I have no idea :(

Comment: @perilbrain I want to know the algorithm T_T

Comment: change your question to "Which algorithm can be used to solve this system of equations?"

Comment: I think there's an O(1) solution, not sure :(

Comment: Try it on paper first (use @starblue 's suggestion).

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just standard linear equations in the field of integers modulo p.

So you can use [Gauss elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_elimination).
The only thing that is a little bit tricky is to compute the [inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: I think it works (I tried it on paper), anyway, is there any algorithms that I can get one of the root of this equation? (I know the algorithms that runs only n * n matrix)